# System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBox' to type 'System.IConvertible'.'

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am tring to move the value which is in textbox3 onto a new page but I keep getting an error (see title)
Anybody know how to fix it?

XAML

```
       <TextBox x:Name="textbox1" Width="200" Height="30" Margin="251,50,349,370" Text="{Binding Content, ElementName=label1}"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="textbox2" Width="200" Height="30" Margin="0,-292,30,328" Text="10"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="textbox3" Width="200" Height="30" Margin="0,-500,45,281" Text="0"/>
```

CS

```
         double v1;
         double v2;
         double.TryParse(textbox1.Text, out v1);
        double.TryParse(textbox2.Text, out v2);
        double v3;
        double.TryParse(textbox3.Text, out v3);

        textbox3.Text = Convert.ToDouble(v1 * v2).ToString();



        TotalHere.TotalNumbers = Convert.ToDouble(textbox3);
        Switcher.Switch(new Page2());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reference the text property rather than the textbox itself.

Try changing this:

```
TotalHere.TotalNumbers = Convert.ToDouble(textbox3);
```

To:

```
TotalHere.TotalNumbers = Convert.ToDouble(textbox3.Text);
```

Comment: Yep, that was it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use `double.TryParse` on the Text property of the textBox instead of directly passing it.

Advantage of `TryParse` method is that you can also check whether the given value is convertible to double or not based on its return value true or false.

Read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=net-7.0)

If not then you can also handle that case as well.